# ¿Cómo puedo obtener de un archivo la cantidad de valores numéricos que son mayores a 20 en java?

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo .txt cargado con nombres y números contenido de un *archivo.txt*

```
Carmen 43, Julia 55, Eric 11
```

necesito saber de los números en el archivo, la cantidad que son mayores a 20.

Es decir que en ese caso la respuesta sería = 2.

Agradezco su apoyo.

En la primera clase:

```
void Asinar(LinkedList registro)
{
this.registro = registro;
        convertir_String(); 
}

void convertir_String()
{ r = registro.toString(); }

void crearArchivo()
 {
 try { // VERIFICA EXISTENCIA DEL ARCHIVO
  if (!file.exists()) 
{ file.createNewFile();}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write(r);
bw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

En la clase del main:

```
for (int i =0; i <= 1; i++)

{   System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");

nombre = sc.next();
System.out.println("Ingrese edad: ");
edad = sc.next();
  //INSERTA DATOS EN LINKEDLIST
registro.add(nombre + "," +edad);
}

obj.Asinar(registro);
obj.crearArchivo();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: @Annel Frank nos puedes compartir que avances o que codigo tienes y en donde tienes dificultades

Comment: Recorre palabra a palabra el txt y mira si la palabra es un numero y si este > 20. Para más detalles, añade código a la pregunta

Comment: @Cadeq  añadí parte del código en la descripción de la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: @Gdaimon añadí parte del código en la descripción de la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: y cual es el problema annel? tene en cuenta que aca no resolvemos ejercicios, pero te podemos ayudar con un problema puntual.

Comment: @AnnelFrank separa los valores usando split() y obtendrás un array, en base a esto puedes trabajar para obtener los valores.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes realizar fácilmente pero debes conocer el funcionamiento de los siguientes métodos :

> - [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) :  Divide esta cadena alrededor de coincidencias de la expresión regular dada.
> - [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) : Devuelve una cadena que es una subcadena de esta cadena. La subcadena comienza en el beginIndex especificado y se
>     extiende al carácter en el índice endIndex - 1. Por lo tanto, la
>     longitud de la subcadena es endIndex-beginIndex.
> - [Integer.parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) : obtiene valor entero representado por el argumento en decimal.

Primero obtiene un array de elementos usando como separador  "," , posteriormente itera sobre estos valores obteniendo los valores numéricos, conviértelos a valores enteros para que estos puedan compararse con el valor de 20.

---

```
    String contenidoArchivo = "Carmen 43, Julia 55, Eric 11";   

    //Crea arreglo de elementos mediante el separador ","
    String[] usuarios = contenidoArchivo.split(",");

    //Contador para usuarios con valor mayor a 20
    int contador = 0;

    for(String usuario : usuarios){
        usuario = usuario.trim(); //Elimina espacio en los extremos.
        //Obtiene valor numerico
        String valorEdad = usuario.substring(usuario.indexOf(" ") + 1, usuario.length() );
        //Convierte el valor numerico y lo compara con 20
        if(Integer.parseInt(valorEdad) > 20){
            contador++;
        }            
    }

    System.out.println("Usuarios con valores mayor a 20: " + contador);
```

Salida:

```
Usuarios con valores mayor a 20: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

**Forma 1**:
Cree una clase, porque no conozco la estructura que estas manejando

```
class Empleado {
    String nombre;
    Integer edad;

    public Integer getEdad ( ) {
        return edad;
    }
}

List < Empleado > empleados = new ArrayList <> ( );
Integer mayores = 0;
// Obtenemos los valores y los asignamos a una Lista
for ( int indice = 0; indice <= 1; indice++ ) {    
    Empleado empleado = new Empleado ( );
    System.out.println ( "Ingrese edad: " );
    empleado.nombre = new Scanner ( System.in ).next ( );
    System.out.println ( "Ingrese edad: " );
    empleado.edad = new Scanner ( System.in ).nextInt ( );
    empleados.add ( empleado );
}
// Creamos un contador y recorremos la lista
for ( Empleado empleado : empleados ){
    if(empleado.edad > 20){
        // Cada vez que encontremos un coincidencia adicionamos
        mayores++;
    }

}
```

**Forma 2**: sin el uso de la clase

```
List < Integer > edades = new ArrayList <> ( );
Integer mayores = 0;
// Obtenemos los valores y los asignamos a una Lista
for ( int indice = 0; indice <= 1; indice++ ) {     
    System.out.println ( "Ingrese Nombre: " );
    String nombre = new Scanner ( System.in ).next ( );
    System.out.println ( "Ingrese edad: " );
    int edad = new Scanner ( System.in ).nextInt ( );
    edades.add ( edad );
}   

// Creamos un contador y recorremos la lista    
for ( int edad : edades ){
    if(edad > 20){
        // Cada vez que encontremos un coincidencia adicionamos
        mayores++;
    }
}
```